# Not getting expected response from Guzzle

Tags: php, curl, slim, guzzle

I'm trying to build an endpoint that forwards the data passed to it to an API using the Slim PHP Framework and I'm having trouble getting my response from a Guzzle request.

```
$app->map( '/api_call/:method', function( $method ) use( $app ){
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
        'base_url' => $app->config( 'api_base_url' ),
        'defaults' => [
            'query'   => [ 'access_token' => 'foo' ],
        ]
    ]);

    $request = $client->createRequest( $app->request->getMethod(), $method, [
        'query' => $app->request->params()
    ]);

    var_dump( $client->send( $request )->getBody() );

})->via( 'GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE' )->conditions( [ 'route' => '.+?' ] );`
```

This then gives me...

```
object(GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream)[59]
  private 'stream' => resource(72, stream)
  private 'size' => null
  private 'seekable' => boolean true
  private 'readable' => boolean true
  private 'writable' => boolean true
  private 'meta' => 
    array (size=6)
     'wrapper_type' => string 'PHP' (length=3)
      'stream_type' => string 'TEMP' (length=4)
      'mode' => string 'w+b' (length=3)
      'unread_bytes' => int 0
      'seekable' => boolean true
      'uri' => string 'php://temp' (length=10)
```

...instead of the response of 'cool' I was expecting.

If I just var_dump `$client->sendRequest( $request )` I get a 200 OK, and the url is what I expect, `http://localhost:8000/test?access_token=foo`.

I have another request, but only using `$client->post(...)` and it works fine without giving me the stream thing back.

I've tried reading the stream using the example at the bottom (http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/http-client/response.html) but it's telling me `feof` doesn't exist.

Anyone have any idea what I'm missing or doing wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Guzzlehttp - How get the body of a response from Guzzle 6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549226/guzzlehttp-how-get-the-body-of-a-response-from-guzzle-6)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The body that you are var_dumping is a Guzzle stream object. This object can be treated like a string or read from as needed. [Documentation for Guzzle Stream here](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/psr7.html#streams)

Comment: Yes, but it shouldn't be, that's not what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, I'm being daft and reading properly. All fine now. Thanks.

Answer (score 27):

Could be;

```
$response = $client->send($request)->getBody()->getContents();
$response = $client->send($request)->getBody()->read(1024*100000);
```

This also work as a shorthand;

```
$response = ''. $client->send($request)->getBody();
$response = (string) $client->send($request)->getBody();
```

// see `__toString()` method for last examples: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring

Answer (score 13):

I was having the same issue, and the thing is, if you getBody its a stream, which means it has a pointer, when you do getContents on it its leaving the pointer in the end of the file, which means if you want to get the body multiple times you need to seek the pointer back to 0.

```
$html1 = $this->response->getBody()->getContents();
$this->response->getBody()->seek(0);
$html2 = $this->response->getBody()->getContents();
$this->response->getBody()->seek(0);
```

This should work :)

@mrW I hope this helps you

Comment: Thanx! Yes, in some cases that will help.

Answer (score 3):

Just had a strange situation. Note that you can get body content only once!

I have expected to get same content every time I call `getContents()`.

```
$html1 = $this->response->getBody()->getContents();
$html2 = $this->response->getBody()->getContents();

$same = ($html1 == $html2);

strlen($html1); //x
strlen($html2); //0
```

**But they are not!** I have missed information that Guzzle response is `stream` so with first `getContents()` we read all contents and *nothing is left for second call*.