# Error passing an instance of an object into a class constructor

Tags: php, oop, guzzle, psr-7

I'm having an issue passing a PSR-7 message response (generated by Guzzle) into a class constructor.

The message is generated by:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->request('GET', 'http://pagecrawler/cache.html');
```

And my class constructor:

```
Class Test {

    protected $response;

    public function __construct($response, $db = null)
    {
        $this->$response = $response; /* Line 18 */
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response could not be converted to string
```

I'd assumed that, as I'm not setting a type for `$this->response`, it would assign the variable without issue.

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549226/guzzlehttp-how-get-the-body-of-a-response-from-guzzle-6 ?

Comment: $this->response, not $this->$response

Comment: @Federico thank you, that was it! Stupid mistake - all my other variable setups (`$this->db = $db`, etc) were correct. Care to add it as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a typo. With `$this->$response` you cast the Response object to a string. Instead you should do `$this->response`.