# Accessing specific properties from Guzzle response?

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm using Guzzle to get an HTTP response. If I do this:

```
$response = $res->getBody();
```

I get an object with 'email' as one of the properties. But if I do either:

```
$email = $res->getBody()->email;
```

or

```
$email = $response->email
```

I get a 'No value for email' error. What am I missing?? How can I access a specific property in the response object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `getBody` method returns an instance of [StreamInterface](https://github.com/php-fig/http-message/blob/master/src/StreamInterface.php). You first need to [retrieve the contents of the response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30549372/711206):

```
$response = (string) $res->getBody();
```

Only then you can decode the json payload:

```
$json = json_decode($response); 
$email = $json->email;
```

Comment: This feels hacky and ugly, really there's no better workaround?

Comment: You could do all at one line. Like: `json_decode($res->getBody())->email`