# How to get body in Guzzle?

Tags: php, guzzle, guzzle6

I use this request:

```
  $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $options = [
            'form_params' => [
                "tip" => "P",
                "voen" => "V",
                "voen" => $voen,
                "submit" => "Yoxla",
            ],
        ];
        $res = $client->request('POST', 'https://www.ebyn/payerOrVoenChecker.jsp', $options);

        dd($res->getBody());
```

As result I get this:

```
Stream {#340 ▼
  -stream: stream resource @424 ▼
    wrapper_type: "PHP"
    stream_type: "TEMP"
    mode: "w+b"
    unread_bytes: 0
    seekable: true
    uri: "php://temp"
    options: []
  }
  -size: null
  -seekable: true
  -readable: true
  -writable: true
  -uri: "php://temp"
  -customMetadata: []
}
```

So, how to get real body, it is HTML page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Guzzlehttp - How get the body of a response from Guzzle 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549226/guzzlehttp-how-get-the-body-of-a-response-from-guzzle-6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution:

```
$res->getBody()->getContents();
```

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53023314/guzzle-returning-stream) for details.