# Where to store the JWT for authentication when Laravel is used as client?

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, guzzle

I use Laravel 6 and GuzzleHTTP 7.

I could manage to make a request to an external (REST-) API and successfully authorize and get a token back:

```
{"access_token":"FooXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2MjExNjkyNDQsImlhdCI6MTYxODU3aNzI0NCwibmJmIjoxNjE4NTc3MjQ0LCJpZGVudGl0eSI6MTQzfQ.wdDzVbE-5O8mfsIqzNvXFpv7THkYYp522HMpyEc8LX0BAR"}
```

Do I have to save this token explicitly in a session?
I'm trying to use this token in every following requests to the external API.

By googling I found only tutorials for Laravel how to generate JWT but not how to proceed when Laravel is used as a client and requests JWT.

Any help much appreciated!

UPDATE: The Laravel APP itself is the client (regardless of the user "inside" Laravel).

Comment: If your app itself is the client and that's irrespective of which user is making the request to your app, then store the token in a database or a persitent(ish) cache. If the token is based on which user is making the request to your app, (e.g. if the JWT token is generated to make requests on behalf of a user, meaning it's different per user) then store it in the session

Comment: I agree, if your laravel app is not separated as backend and frontend, then you can use database or I would prefer a cache such as memcached or redis to save it for the session, if logs out then clear it out

Comment: What happens when the JWT token is refreshed eg. month? Is there a way to keep the token valid eg. replaced with the new token automatically?

Comment: Personally I use the database cache driver for things that last longer. You can use something like `Cache::driver('database')->remember('jwt_token', 2629746, function() { /* get the token */ })` so anywhere this code is ran it will get a new token if there's none in the cache or the one in the cache is expired. You need to [set up the database as a cache](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/cache#prerequisites-database) beforehand though

Comment: whenever you fetch the jwt code check the time if the current time is 5 min less than expiry then update the token

Comment: Q1) Does each user need a different JWT token when accessing the 3rd party API, or will 1 JWT token be sufficient for all users. Q2) Also does the JWT token expire. Q3) If it does expire, does the JWT response have a refresh token.

Comment: A1) All (Laravel-)user has the same JWT token. A2) Yes, JWT token expires but I don't know exactly when. A3) Yes, I have to elaborate this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon getting your token from a 3rd party service, store it in some form of storage (e.g. file, database, cache). I recommend using a Cache, as it's faster (if your using an in-memory cache like Redis), and you can set a TTL.

If the token expires after a certain period of time, and doesn't have a refresh token, then set the TTL to that date/time.

Example:

```
$ttl = Carbon::now()->addHour(); // set to when it expires or null if token doesn't expire
$jwtToken = Cache::remember('fooServiceJwtToken', $ttl, function () {
    $jwt = getJwtTokenUsingGuzzle(); // CHANGE
    return $jwt;
});
```

Do not store the data in a session, as sessions are tied to users using your application.

Comment: Ok, sounds good, thank you! One question though: What does TTL mean?

Comment: Time to live. In other words when it expires.