# object in array to retrieve values ​separately with json encode, json decode, but the array return null

Tags: php, arrays, json, guzzle

I'm PHP junior developer, and I still have to learn so please be understanding :)

I use Ninja API to return information about cars, this API returns an object, and everything works correctly,
but I need this information separately and I can't do it like for arrays "`$array[...]`",
so I used the JSON encode and JSON decode to transform my object into a array.

When I try to echo my array everything works but when I try to return a value into a array I have this error:

> "Warning: Undefined array key "make"".

When I do this:

```
echo gettype($array);
```

I have this:

```
array(0) { } array
```

but when I just call my array like this:

```
var_dump($array);
```

or

```
echo $array;
```

I have this:

```
[{"city_mpg": 23, "class": "subcompact car", "combination_mpg": 26, 
    "cylinders": 4, "displacement": 1.6, "drive": "fwd", "fuel_type": "gas",
    "highway_mpg": 31, "make": "nissan", "model": "sentra classic", 
    "transmission": "a", "year": 1995}, 
{"city_mpg": 25, "class": "subcompact car", "combination_mpg": 28,
    "cylinders": 4, "displacement": 1.6, "drive": "fwd", "fuel_type": "gas",
    "highway_mpg": 34, "make": "nissan", "model": "sentra classic",
    "transmission": "m", "year": 1995}]
```

My class:

```
<?php

namespace Infrastructure\dataProviders;

use Domain\Request\SearchCarRequest;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Domain\UseCase\SearchCarUseCase;

class carsSearchApi
{

public $car;
private string $ApiKey = "...";

public function __construct($model)
{
    $client = new Client();

    $response = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.api-ninjas.com/v1/cars?limit=2&model=' . 
    $model, [
        'headers' => [
            'X-RapidAPI-Host' => 'cars-by-api-ninjas.p.rapidapi.com',
            "X-Api-Key" => $this->ApiKey,
        ]
    ]);
    $searchCar = new SearchCarUseCase();

    echo $car = $response->getBody();
    $car_encoded = json_encode($response->getBody());
    $car_decoded = json_decode($car_encoded, true);

    var_dump($car_decoded);
    echo gettype($car_decoded);

    $searchCar->returnApi($car_decoded);

}

}
```

before doing the JSON decode, JSON encode, when I "echo" my object it displayed things the same way as when I "echo" the array or "var_dump" the array, this:

```
[{"city_mpg": 23, "class": "subcompact car", "combination_mpg": 26, 
    "cylinders": 4, "displacement": 1.6, "drive": "fwd", "fuel_type": "gas",
    "highway_mpg": 31, "make": "nissan", "model": "sentra classic", 
    "transmission": "a", "year": 1995}, 
{"city_mpg": 25, "class": "subcompact car", "combination_mpg": 28,
    "cylinders": 4, "displacement": 1.6, "drive": "fwd", "fuel_type": "gas",
    "highway_mpg": 34, "make": "nissan", "model": "sentra classic",
    "transmission": "m", "year": 1995}]
```

but then I `var_dump` it (before the JSON encode, decode, when it was an object), I have this:

```
object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream)#404 (7) { ["stream":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=> resource(480) of type (stream)
["size":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=> NULL ["seekable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=> bool(true)
["readable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=> bool(true) ["writable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=> bool(true)
["uri":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=> string(10) "php://temp" ["customMetadata":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
array(0) { } } array(0) { }
```

I use Guzzlehttp in this class to call the API,

If you need more information do not hesitate.

I haven't been able to find how to do the line breaks, if someone can tell me that would be cool,

In short I need to know why I can't select the values ​​of my array even though they exist, and why my array shows as empty when I do a `gettype()`, how can I select the values ​​from my array.

Comment: I thought maybe I had an object in my array, it's possible if I'm not wrong, and that could explain why the array appears empty

Comment: `$car_encoded = json_encode($response->getBody());`.... I sincerely doubt that this makes sense or is needed. More than likely, the string in the raw response is _already_ JSON. So then encoding it as JSON again will, at best, cause double-encoding which is entirely redudant. You can double-check by echoing the result of `$response->getBody()` directly, but basically I expect all you need to to is just write `$car_decoded = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);` in order to get that JSON response into a PHP array

Comment: `echo $array;` would only result in the _literal_ text `Array`, _if_ `$array` actually _was_ an array. According to the text output you are getting, it is clearly not - it is a string, containing JSON.

Comment: You also may need to pay attention to exactly how you retrieve the response from Guzzle. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30549372/5947043 and https://guzzle3.readthedocs.io/http-client/response.html#response-body . It looks like the body comes back as a stream object (`GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream`), so you need to actually fetch the contents, or at the very least explicitly cast it to a string. That _might_ explain what's happening (I am not a regular Guzzle user, I'm just simply reading the documentation and searching online about that getBody() function, as anyone could do if they decided to....)

Comment: @ADyson 
it makes so much sense, thank you very much, it solved my problem, sorry for bothering you with that

Comment: `echo gettype($array);` just echoes the word `array`. I don't know how you're getting `array(0) { } array`. The first part looks like `var_dump()` of an empty array.